# Converting list of JSON pages to one object

Tags: python, json

I want to create program which uses api to generate some data/statistics.

Api is presented on 32 pages, so I have to iterate, add page to list and after getting all of them I want to convert elements in list to one huge object and operate on him.

So, to get data from API and store in the list I have:

```
response = []

for i in range(1,32):
    url = "https://api.dane.gov.pl/resources/17201/data?page="+str(i)
    response.append(requests.get(url).json)
```

I was trying using json.loads(), json.dumps() but nothing worked. Any solution idea hot to solve this?

**EDIT:**
when I collect my response and use:

```
valid = json.dumps(response)
print(valid)
```

I got error:
Object of type 'method' is not JSON serializable

Comment: technically `{"response": response}` is a valid JSON. Did you mean another thing?

Comment: @bergerg well, if I just want to use 1 page I dont have problem to get data from my response. I just parse him using json.loads and djson.dumps().
But atm my response is a list and I want to convert whole list to one huge json object

Comment: no, I mean that an object containing a list of valid JSON is a valid JSON by itself. So after you "collect" all the responses into a list, just dump them as part of a new object.

Comment: Or did you mean how to UNIFY those response objects into one ginormous object which contains the same fields as a single response. If this is the case you will have to give some more details on the schema of the response JSON.

Comment: @Frendom you need to call the function `json()`. Like this `response.append(requests.get(url).json())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import json

def collect_responses(num_of_pages):
    response = []

    for i in range(1, num_of_pages):
        url = "https://api.dane.gov.pl/resources/17201/data?page="+str(i)
        response.append(requests.get(url).json())
    return response

valid = json.dumps({"responseList": collect_responses(32)}
```

Or in a more general way:

```
def paginate_while_200(url_template_missing_pagenum):
    list_of_json_response = []
    i = 1
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url % i)
        if response.status == 200:
            try:
                list_of_json_response.append(response.json())
                i += 1
            finally:
                return list_of_json_response
        else:
            return list_of_json_response

url = "https://api.dane.gov.pl/resources/17201/data?page=%d"
json.dumps({"responseList": paginate_while_200(url)})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error - Object of type 'method' is not JSON serializable

Comment: Looks like you omitted the call: `.json()`

Comment: It seems to me that it looks like it should, thank you ;)

Comment: @bergerg or not: valid = json.dumps({"responseList": collect_response(32)}) is a str not huge Response type. And I need a Response because I want to extract date based on name of the fields. And it works for me if I use only 1 page to get data, but not in this way

Comment: @Frendom just load it back with `json.loads` or don't dump it. I just followed your question's edit.